My Solana Trading bot gives sbf panic error
#7 Jupiter Aggregator v6 instruction

Program log: Instruction: SharedAccountsRoute
Invoking Token Program
Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked
Program Token Program consumed 6238 of 1333397 compute units
Program returned success
Program log: panicked at 'range end index 72 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token.rs:537:39
Program Jupiter Aggregator v6 consumed 34458 of 1350793 compute units
Program returned error: SBF program panicked


if you run into "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 72 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token.rs:537:39" error, that means that you are missing the necessary token accounts to swap to and from.
this can happen if you are skipping setupInstructions if you are using /swap-instructions.
